# How to add a row to the top of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read my data by this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r' ...\x.csv')
```

Then specify choose some of them like this:

```
dataset = dataset.loc[len(dataset)-data_length:  , :]
```

Do shifting:

```
dataset_shifted = dataset.shift(1)
dataset_shifted = dataset_shifted.dropna()
```

And like to add a new row equal to 1 to the top of my `dataset`. But using the following command doesn't work because my data indexes are from 3714 to 3722 and it adds an index 0 to end of the dataframe not to the top of it!

```
dataset_shifted = dataset_shifted .loc[0 , :] = 1
```

Comment: You can easily do a concat of a new dataframe with new values to the original one and it will show at the top. I can't think of a reason this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no missing values in `DataFrame` you can simplify your solution by remove `dropna` and using [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9],
         'D':[1,3,5],

}, index=[3714, 3715, 3716])

print (dataset)
      B  C  D
3714  4  7  1
3715  5  8  3
3716  4  9  5

dataset_shifted = dataset.shift(1).fillna(1)
print (dataset_shifted)
        B    C    D
3714  1.0  1.0  1.0
3715  4.0  7.0  1.0
3716  5.0  8.0  3.0
```

If possible missing values only set first row by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
dataset_shifted = dataset.shift(1)
dataset_shifted.iloc[0 , :] = 1
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
dataset_shifted = dataset.shift(1)
dataset_shifted = dataset_shifted.dropna()
dataset_shifted.loc[0 , :] = 1
dataset_shifted = dataset_shifted.sort_index()

print (dataset_shifted)
        B    C    D
0     1.0  1.0  1.0
3715  4.0  7.0  1.0
3716  5.0  8.0  3.0
```

Comment: These don't add a new row! it only changes the value of first existing row!

Comment: @user145959 - Sorry, I miss it, solution was changed.